# Rails 5 redirect with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

Controller:

```
def foo
 redirect_to home_path(params: auth_params)
end

private
def auth_params
  params.require(:auth).permit(:name, :email, :photo_url, :provider, :provider_id)
end
```

Here are the parameters that the controller errors out on:

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"...",
 "auth"=>
  {"name"=>"...",
   "email"=>"...",
   "photo_url"=>"...",
   "provider"=>"...",
   "provider_id"=>"..."}
}
```

With this error: `unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash`

I permit all the params (with the exception of the rails default params (i.e. utf8, authenticity_token, so why is this error popping up?

EDIT:

Neither of the following suggestions are working either:

```
redirect_to home_path(auth_params)
redirect_to home_path, params: auth_params
```

A little more info on how I get to the controller action might help:

I have (in the same controller) an action `bar` that has a `form_tag` in the view that goes to foo_path. I've tried submitting the form via jQuery or a submit button, it doesn't change the result. As soon as I hit the `auth_params` method I get the error.

This means it is erroring out on the `auth_params` method rather than the redirect itself

Comment: Have you tried just with `home_path(params)`?

Comment: pass `auth_params` instead of `params: auth_params`

Comment: neither of those do the trick. see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I restarted the development server AND cleared all the cookies placed by rails (most notably the `app-name` session cookie), the normal strong parameter syntax (i.e. params.require().permit()) works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have get this error too when I have upgrade to Rails 5.1.4. I fixed with this

```
redirect_to(home_path, params: params.require(:auth).permit(:name, :email, :photo_url, :provider, :provider_id))
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `home_path` and other `url_for` related methods are expecting a Hash object instead of an `ActionController::Parameters` object (which is what the `params` method in controllers returns) so you need to convert it to a hash first, like so:

```
redirect_to home_path(auth_params.to_h)
```

Answer (score 0):

You´re doing it very wrong. If you are creating a resource then you should reply to validation errors by rendering a view - not redirecting.

The response you´re sending the user is the result of performing a non-idempotent action.

This might seem like nitpicking but outing the users email & chosen password in the GET parameters is pretty reckless.

If you are embedding a form in your homepage its pretty simple to just create a `auths/new.html.erb` view which just shows the form and lets the user correct the misstakes:

```
class AuthsController

  def create
    @auth = Auth.new(auth_params)
    if @auth.save
      redirect_to some_path, success: "Your account was created"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
   def auth_params
     params.require(:auth).permit(:name, :email, :photo_url, :provider, :provider_id)
   end
end
```

If the form has to be seamlessly included in the home page then you need to render that view or use ajax to perform it in place.